# How to filter PID from Linux SSH security logs?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, regular-expression, logs

```
  Aug 12 01:30:26 server.example.com sshd[19486]: Failed password for root from X.X.X.X port 50528 ssh2
  Aug 12 01:30:26 server.example.com sshd[19486]: Received disconnect from X.X.X.X port 50528:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
  Aug 12 01:30:26 server.example.com sshd[19486]: Disconnected from X.X.X.X port 50528 [preauth]
  Aug 12 01:30:28 server.example.com sshd[19491]: Failed password for root from X.X.X.X port 59628 ssh2
```

I have a sample Linux SSH log file pulled from "/var/log/secure". I would like filter the PID (19491 and 19486 in this example). How can I achieve this using bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk -F '[][]' '{print $2}'  /var/log/secure
```

- `-F '[][]'` to have files separator as open and close braces
- `$2`  to validate the second field.

Comment: I would like to have that as a variable since I have thousands of those PIDs in the log file

Comment: I still get full output instead of just the PIDs

Comment: _"I would like to have that as a variable..."_   For future reference, so you can get the most out of SE, @BruceMalaudzi, issues like this should be in the question.

Comment: @Siva Thanks for the advise. Your final answers has been accepted and upvoted. Works like a charm. I understand my question was bit lame.

Answer (score 0):

This is bit clumsy but I hope someone can post a shorter version:
I used sed command to replace the "[" and "]" characters with empty spaces, and then used awk command to print 6th field

```
# cat /var/log/secure | sed 's/\[/ /g' | sed 's/\]/ /g' | awk ' {print $6}'
19486
19486
19486
19491
```

Comment: You have a [Useless Use of cat](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html) and four processes invoked.  Keeping your approach but simplifying, consider `sed 's/[^[]*\[//; s/\].*//' /var/log/secure`